# Logistic growth curve using scipy is not quite right

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations

I'm trying to fit a simple logistic growth model to dummy data using Python's `Scipy` package. The code is shown below, along with the output that I get. The correct output is shown below it. I'm not quite sure what's going wrong here.

```
import scipy.optimize as optim
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N0 = 0.37
parsic = [.25, 12.9]

df_yeast = pd.DataFrame({'cd': [9.6, 18.3, 29., 47.2, 71.1, 119.1, 174.6, 257.3, 350.7, 441., 513.3, 559.7, 594.8, 629.4, 640.8, 651.1, 655.9, 659.6], 'td': np.arange(18)})

def logistic_de(t, N, r, K):
    return r*N*(1 - N/K)

def logistic_solution(t, r, K):
    return odeint(logistic_de, N0, t, (r, K), tfirst=True).ravel()

params, _ = optim.curve_fit(logistic_solution, df_yeast['td'], df_yeast['cd'], p0=parsic)

N1 = odeint(logistic_de, N0, np.linspace(0, 20, 10000), (params[0], params[1]), tfirst=True)

plt.plot(np.linspace(0, 20, 10000), N1)
plt.scatter(df_yeast['td'], df_yeast['cd'])
plt.ylabel('num yeast')
plt.xlabel('time')
```

My output:
[image]

Correct output:
[image]

Comment: Make `N0` an additional parameter of `logistic_solution` (see @DavisHerring's answer).  Use the limits of the known data as a reasonable initial guess of the parameters, e.g. `N0=9.6`, `K=660`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser could you include the code to fix this?

Comment: @AnIgnorantWanderer: The comment already says what to do, doesn’t it?  Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service, although it appears that someone has been so kind as to oblige.

Comment: @DavisHerring it does say what to do, I tried just adding it as a parameter, but something else needed to be done as well

Comment: @Davis Herring I gave OP the benefit of the doubt that they tried an edit of the `logistic_solution` function as suggested and adjusted the `curve_fit` line to make the code run, but it's very possible to miss the edit of `N1` and get the wrong result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the edit they're hinting at, maybe this'll help you understand:

```
# include N0 as an argument
def logistic_solution(t, N0, r, K):
    return odeint(logistic_de, N0, t, (r, K), tfirst=True).ravel()

# N0 thus included as parameter to fit
params, _ = optim.curve_fit(logistic_solution, df_yeast['td'], df_yeast['cd'], 
                            p0=[N0, *parsic])

# N1 integral factors in the fitted N0 parameter
# (not the same as the global variable named N0,
# should change global variable to something like N0_guess)
N1 = odeint(logistic_de, params[0], np.linspace(0, 20, 10000), 
            tuple(params[1:]), tfirst=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your optimization does not allow changing `N0`, which is dramatically different from the actual *t*=0 value in the list.

Comment: could you include the code to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

why not try fit growth curve directly

```
def my_logistic(t, a, b, c):
    return c / (1 + a * np.exp(-b*t))

params, _ = optim.curve_fit(my_logistic, 
                            df_yeast['td'], df_yeast['cd'],
                            p0=np.random.exponential(size=3),
                            bounds=(0,[100000., 3., 700]))
N1 = my_logistic(np.linspace(0, 20, 10000),*params)

plt.plot(np.linspace(0, 20, 10000), N1)
plt.scatter(df_yeast['td'], df_yeast['cd'])
plt.ylabel('num yeast')
plt.xlabel('time')
```

get the curve below:

[image]

and params:

```
[7.18068070e+01 5.47614074e-01 6.62655252e+02]
```